# Остановить логирование

Tags: php, логирование, hosting

Есть скрипт казино, который Работает на php и флеш играх. Установили, настроили всё хорошо работало, но через неделю произошло переполнение дискового пространства на хостинге (12гб). Само казино весит около 2.1гб. Вот что ответил хостинг:

"Из-за неверно настроенного скрипта сайта,либо массы ошибок в нем, либо уровня логирования забились логи.

```
root@server:/# du -sh /var/www/admin/data/*
4.0K /var/www/admin/data/email
8.0K /var/www/admin/data/etc
13G /var/www/admin/data/logs
4.0K /var/www/admin/data/mod-tmp
0 /var/www/admin/data/tmp
712M /var/www/admin/data/www
```

Логи почистили, но Вам нужно настроить скрипт сайта, если он работает нормально, то уменьшить уровень логирования ошибок либо совсем отключить с помощь error_reporting"

Мы сделали вывод, что скорее всего заполняется история действий пользователя в играх и я подумал на логи. Восстановили бекап, ISP снова начала работать и я начал решать проблему. Отключил логи при помощи:

`php_value error_reporting 0
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag display_startup_errors off`

в файле .htaccess, но это не помогло, память снова продолжала расти. Как объяснила это тех поддержка хостинга:

"На данный момент проблем с логами нет(с их размерами), но пишутся нотайсы как и были. Если не отключается логирование php_value error_reporting 0 , то скрипт cms сайта свои настраивает параметры(заменяя текущие настройки сервера). Это обычно называется режим отладки, либо режим логов. Вам нужно гуглить по своей cms.

```
root@server:/# du -sh /var/www/admin/data/logs/*
1.9M /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.access.log
16K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.access.log.0.gz
12K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.access.log.1.gz
40K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.access.log.2.gz
4.0K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.access.log.3.gz
56K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.error.log
4.0K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.error.log.0.gz
4.0K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.error.log.1.gz
88K /var/www/admin/data/logs/gamegods777.com.error.log.2.gz
```

Может кто знает, как можно остановить это заполнение? Может можно чистить эту информация автоматически, например, каждые два месяца. Отпиши кто сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что про логи и про ошибки которые в них пишутся - это только догадки? И самих логов на 10 терабайт никто не видел?

Comment: Да, мне посоветовали (не на хостинге) отключить логи. Я их отключил, так как написал в вопросе, но это не принесло плоды. За три - четыре часа на хостинге +100 мб.

Comment: А, ну тогда продолжай, продолжай.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, почитай

Comment: Единственные логи, которые здесь привдены, занимают 2 мегабайта. Ни 100 мегабайтами, ни 10 гигабайтами тут и не пахнет. попытайся поискать снова.

Comment: А это не оно:13G /var/www/admin/data/logs?

Comment: самая первая ошибка была поставить чужое казино, хотя это совсем другая история..

Comment: Мы его купили, а после продажи, человек отказался помогать в настройке

Comment: а вы не боитесь что вам на хостинг закачали что то со стороны?

Comment: Если по теме Вам нечего написать, не тратте своё время

Comment: если по теме то надо смотреть какие появились неизвестные файлы и размер базы данных, так же сравнить контрольную сумму известных файлов. найдете с 100 процентной вероятностью. но я бы от первого замечания так как вы не отмахивался.

Comment: Это не логи. Это размер папки целиком, который был когда-то. Сейчас в этой папке лежит логов на 2Мб. Рекомендую продолжить чистить логи, которых нет. Очень продуктивное занятие.

Comment: А функцию `error_reporting` искали поиском по проекту?

Comment: Нет, а если найду, то что нужно предпринять, обьясниите пожалуйста

Comment: error_reporting 0  - это плохая идея,тем более что access_log у вас наполняется в разы быстрее error_log'a. смотрите в сторону настройки апача и nginx'а и logrotat'а

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Логи нужны всегда:

1. Найдите то что занимает место (найти проще утилитой типа http://ashep.org/2013/analiz-ispolzovaniya-diska-pri-pomoshhi-ncdu/ )
2. Настройте правильно logrotate